# write a program that will do a basic transaction of atms in c++. It will decrease the amount of something by how many times it is used

Tags: c++, function, dynamic, static, transactions

I have the part that asks you to enter an amount and it will output what type of notes it must be.(e.g for $220 the output will be 2 $100 and 2 $10.)

I have already did the calculation part mentioned above. I need the function that can store how many hundred etc notes are found in the machine and it must decrease each time they are used. (e.g given above example if there were 10 notes of each, after transaction only 8 notes of each will be left.)

The program must also ask if the user wants to make another transaction after each trans. and if there is not enough notes to do the trans. the program must exit by saying not enough funds. so far i got (i will add the other notes after i am complete with the storing):

```
void Transaction(int dollars, int& thousands, int& hundreds)
{
 thousands=(dollars/1000);
dollars-=thousands*1000;
 hundreds=(dollars/100);
dollars-=hundreds*20;
 }
 int main(void)
 {
 int dollars; 
 int thousands=0;
 int hundreds=0;

 cout<<"Enter the amount:";
 cin>> dollars;

 Transaction(dollars,thousands,hundreds);

 cout<<"$1000 Notes:"<< thousands <<endl;
 cout<<"$100 Notes:"<< hundreds <<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void Transaction(int dollars, int& thousands, int& hundreds, int& p_thousands, int& p_hundreds)
{
  if(p_thousands*1000 + p_hundreds*100 > dollars)
  {
 thousands=(dollars/1000);

  dollars-=thousands*1000;

  hundreds=(dollars/100);

  dollars-=hundreds*20;
  }
  else
  {
  cout << "Not Enough Funds" <<endl;
  exit(0);
  }

  }
 int main(void)
 {
 int dollars; 
 int p_thousands=10;
 int p_hundreds=10;
 int thousands=0;
 int hundreds=0;
 char c;
do
{
cout<<"Enter the amount:";
cin>> dollars;
Transaction(dollars,thousands,hundreds,p_thousands,p_hundreds);
p_thousands  -= thousands;
p_hundreds -= hundreds;
cout<<"$1000 Notes:"<< thousands <<endl;
cout<<"$100 Notes:"<< hundreds <<endl;
// for debugging purpose
//cout<<"$1000 Notes present:" <<p_thousands <<endl;
//cout<<"$100 Notes present:" <<p_hundreds <<endl;
cout<<"Press y for another transaction" <<endl;
cin>>c;
}while(c=='y');


}
```

Comment: wow thanks this was really helpful :).. Oh and how can i add a function where it shows how many notes are left if the user presses n (for no) instead of yes?

Comment: Instesd of do while loop add a while loop and check for the further transaction if y then do what you did earlier and if pressed n then display the notes in the atm

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void Transaction(int dollars, int& thousands, int& hundreds, int& p_thousands, int&     p_hundreds)
{
if(p_thousands*1000 + p_hundreds*100 >= dollars)
{
  if(dollars/1000>p_thousands)
  {
  dollars -=p_thousands*1000;
  thousands =p_thousands;
  }
  else
  {
  thousands=(dollars/1000);
  dollars-=thousands*1000;
  }
  if(dollars/100>p_hundreds)
  {
  dollars -=p_hundreds*100;
  hundreds =p_hundreds;
  }
  else
  {
  hundreds=(dollars/100);
  dollars-=hundreds*20;
  }
}
else
{
cout << "Not Enough Funds" <<endl;
exit(0);
}

}
int main(void)
{
int dollars; 
int p_thousands=10;
int p_hundreds=10;
int thousands=0;
int hundreds=0;
char c;
do
{
cout<<"Enter the amount:";
cin>> dollars;
Transaction(dollars,thousands,hundreds,p_thousands,p_hundreds);
p_thousands  -= thousands;
p_hundreds -= hundreds;
cout<<"$1000 Notes:"<< thousands <<endl;
cout<<"$100 Notes:"<< hundreds <<endl;
// for debugging purpose
cout<<"$1000 Notes present:" <<p_thousands <<endl;
cout<<"$100 Notes present:" <<p_hundreds <<endl;
cout<<"Press y for another transaction" <<endl;
cin>>c;
}while(c=='y');


}
```